# How to ggplot dates on x-axis together with values in this R data structure?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a R data structure which has `numerical` values and `char` dates, after melting together in the field `value`. 
I am thinking how you can manage the variable `Date` after melting for the `ggplot`. 
I would not like to separate a list of dates from the data structure `dat.m` or `molten` before plotting.

1. to take a list of dates before plotting (deprecated) OR
2. to somehow apply the outputs of `variable = Date` (call here `dates`) to the parameter `scale_x_discrete("Date", labels = dates)` OR
3. plot directly somehow with `dat.m`?

Expected output: facet plot with dates `Date` on the x-axis, and other values than `Date` in `molten$value` in y-axis in Fig. 1

Fig. 1 Expected output with dates `Date` on x-axis (sorry, here partially cut out days)

[image]

### Point (2)

Code which output follows

```
dat.m <- structure(list(REM = c(160, 150), kevyt = c(380, 420), syva = c(110, 180), Date = c("1.1.2011",  "2.2.2012")), .Names = c("REM", "kevyt", "syva", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
library("data.table")
str(dat.m)
print(dat.m)

molten <- melt(as.data.table(dat.m, keep.rownames = "Vars"), id.vars = "Vars") # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128640/54964
print("Hello 2")
str(molten)
print(molten)

# TODO take dates from molten[, "Date"]. Here or somehow inside ggplot? Pseudocodes:
# dates <- molten[, "Date"] ... 
# OR
# somehow directly in ggplot

library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = Vars, y = value, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Output

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ REM  : num  160 150
 $ kevyt: num  380 420
 $ syva : num  110 180
 $ Date : chr  "1.1.2011" "2.2.2012"
  REM kevyt syva     Date
1 160   380  110 1.1.2011
2 150   420  180 2.2.2012
Warning message:
In melt.data.table(as.data.table(dat.m, keep.rownames = "Vars"),  :
  'measure.vars' [REM, kevyt, syva, Date] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'character'. All measure variables not of type 'character' will be coerced to. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.
[1] "Hello 2"
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Vars    : chr  "1" "2" "1" "2" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 4 levels "REM","kevyt",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
 $ value   : chr  "160" "150" "380" "420" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
   Vars variable    value
1:    1      REM      160
2:    2      REM      150
3:    1    kevyt      380
4:    2    kevyt      420
5:    1     syva      110
6:    2     syva      180
7:    1     Date 1.1.2011
8:    2     Date 2.2.2012
```

### Point (3)

I cannot simply do the proposal of the thread [R: ggplot display all dates on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856325/54964) because `molten` does not contain only integers but `character` dates too. Pseudocode using directly `dat.m` based on the thread

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856325/54964
ggplot(data = dat.m) + 
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = value, fill = variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
    scale_x_date(date_labels="%s", Dates) # TODO problem here
```

See Point (2) for the rest of the code.

R: 3.4.0 (backports)
OS: Debian 8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want dates on the x axis you need to exclude them from the `melt`...

```
molten <- melt(dat.m, id.vars = "Date")
```

To reproduce (almost) your desired chart, you can do the following...

```
p <- ggplot(molten, aes(x = Date, y = value, colour=variable, group=variable)) + 
            geom_line() + 
            facet_wrap(facets="variable")
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this approach passes my first set of tests. I will continue into the second set of tests.