# Formatting x axis with different dates in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling to format the x-axis of a stacked area plot with ggplot2. This is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(
     Taxon = c("Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms", "Others", "Dinos", "Diatoms"),
     Abundance = c(14192, 120, 440, 6000, 80, 360, 25800, 4384, 169428, 879103, 2000, 52360, 213508, 22560, 470900, 472808, 11920, 316312, 81504, 6280, 15096, 50656, 11360, 43448),
     Date = c("05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "09/03/2019", "09/03/2019", "09/03/2019", "11/04/2019", "11/04/2019", "11/04/2019", "01/05/2019", "01/05/2019", "01/05/2019", "01/06/2019", "01/06/2019", "01/06/2019", "01/07/2019", "01/07/2019", "01/07/2019", "01/08/2019", "01/08/2019", "01/08/2019", "01/09/2019","01/09/2019", "01/09/2019")
)

df %>% group_by(Date, Taxon) %>% summarise_all(sum) -> df1

ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.Date(Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"), Abundance, colour=Taxon, fill=Taxon)) + geom_area(stat="identity", position="stack") + labs(x = "", y = "") + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m/%Y")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image: ggplot2]

My questions are now:

1. How do I get the x axis labels to correspond to the dates in df2$Date and not the first of the month?
2. I would like all dates to be visible on the x axis. I tried to use `scale_x_continuous(labels=dates)` 
   with `dates <- unique(df1$Date)` but this gives me an error. How do I get it right?

I would very much appreciate any hints!

Comment: If you want to adjust the breaks (i.e. the values at which labels are shown) that's with the `date_breaks` argument, not the `date_labels` argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: ggplot display all dates on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855673/r-ggplot-display-all-dates-on-x-axis)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Jonathan provided what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_date` as the same object that you assigned to `labels`.

```
scale_x_date(labels = as.Date(df1$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"), 
breaks = as.Date(df1$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the breaks argument

To change date frequency, you have to use the `break` argument on `scale_x_date()` function, like this:

```
+ scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m/%Y"), breaks = date_breaks("2 weeks"))
```

This is the complete code for a graph with `2 weeks` break:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df1 %>% ggplot(aes(
  x = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
  Abundance,
  colour = Taxon,
  fill = Taxon
)) +
  geom_area(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m/%Y"), breaks = date_breaks("2 weeks")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Jonathan's answer was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the `date_breaks` argument in `scale_x_date`, ie.:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.Date(Date, format="%d/%m/%Y"), Abundance, colour=Taxon, fill=Taxon)) + 
  geom_area(stat="identity", position="stack") + labs(x = "", y = "") + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%d/%m/%Y"),date_breaks = '1 week') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```