# How to order geom_segment ggplot with colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to `ggplot` library. And trying to draw the plot using the following `data.frame`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <-tribble(~event, ~startdate,~enddate,~loc,
      "A",as.POSIXct("1984/02/10"),as.POSIXct("1987/06/10"),"1",
      "B",as.POSIXct("1984/02/11"),as.POSIXct("1990/02/12"),"2",
      "A",as.POSIXct("1992/05/15"),as.POSIXct("1999/06/15"),"3",
      "C",as.POSIXct("2003/08/29"),as.POSIXct("2015/08/29"),"4",
      "B",as.POSIXct("2002/04/11"),as.POSIXct("2012/04/12"),"5",
      "E",as.POSIXct("2000/02/10"),as.POSIXct("2005/02/15"),"6")
max_date = max(df$startdate,df$enddate)
```

Using the following code snippet:

```
ggplot(NULL)+
  geom_segment(data = df,aes(x=loc, xend =loc,y = startdate, yend = enddate,colour=event),size = 5,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_label(aes(label=df$event,x = df$loc,y=max_date), size=2) +
  #geom_point(data=final_df,aes(x=newspaper,y=date),color="black") + Point from other data frame
  coord_flip() + xlab("LoC") + ylab("Year")
```

I can able to output the following chart:[image]

How can I order the above chart using the colour i.e. using the `event` field (in other word how can I perform group by operation on the `event` field so that first **it should display first all events A then events B, C** etc.)? I have tried to use `scale_x_continuous` and `reorder` from `tidyverse` package but it didn't work. How can I display more "Year" on the x-axis? I tried to use `scale_x_date` (mentioned here [R: ggplot display all dates on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855673/r-ggplot-display-all-dates-on-x-axis) but it needs `as.Date` and `ggplot` `geom_segment` needs `as.POSIXct` format). Please feel free to correct me!

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: you can reorder by event, but then your LoC would not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options. I've also reversed your x and y so you don't have to use `coord_flip()` and made several other small modifications including the x-axis labels (you were looking for `scale_y_datetime` since you flipped the axes and the "dates" were actually in POSIXct). Also, one difference with Duck's answer is my scales = "free" in `facet_grid`. You might decide your labels and your "loc" variable may not make sense given these new graphs anyway.

```r
library(tibble); library(ggplot2)
df <-tribble(~event, ~startdate,~enddate,~loc,
             "A",as.POSIXct("1984/02/10"),as.POSIXct("1987/06/10"),"1",
             "B",as.POSIXct("1984/02/11"),as.POSIXct("1990/02/12"),"2",
             "A",as.POSIXct("1992/05/15"),as.POSIXct("1999/06/15"),"3",
             "C",as.POSIXct("2003/08/29"),as.POSIXct("2015/08/29"),"4",
             "B",as.POSIXct("2002/04/11"),as.POSIXct("2012/04/12"),"5",
             "E",as.POSIXct("2000/02/10"),as.POSIXct("2005/02/15"),"6")
max_date = max(df$startdate,df$enddate)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(aes(y=event, yend = event, x = startdate, xend = enddate, colour=event),size = 5,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_label(aes(label=event, y = event, x=max_date), size=2) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("LoC") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(aes(y=loc, yend = loc, x = startdate, xend = enddate, colour=event),size = 5,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_label(aes(label=event, y = loc, x=max_date), size=2) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("LoC") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(event), scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You might keep the "loc" variable so that each item has its own row/line.If they don't really mean anything, then you could cover up the y-axis in post processing.

Comment: Could you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470942/how-to-order-primary-y-axis-within-label-in-ggplot

Answer (score 1):

Consider this as an option, as mentioned by **@ArthurYip** setting reorder could affect the sense of your plot. You could avoid the labels and using `facet_grid()` in next way:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=loc, xend =loc,y = startdate, yend = enddate,colour=event),size = 5,alpha=0.6) +
  coord_flip() + xlab("LoC") + ylab("Year")+
  facet_grid(event~.,switch = "x")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470942/how-to-order-primary-y-axis-within-label-in-ggplot