# How to order primary Y axis within label in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

I am new to `ggplot` library. And trying to draw the plot using the following `data.frame`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tribble(~event, ~startdate,~enddate,~loc,
      "A",as.POSIXct("1984/02/10"),as.POSIXct("1987/06/10"),"1",
      "B",as.POSIXct("1984/02/11"),as.POSIXct("1990/02/12"),"2",
      "A",as.POSIXct("1992/05/15"),as.POSIXct("1999/06/15"),"3",
      "C",as.POSIXct("2003/08/29"),as.POSIXct("2015/08/29"),"4",
      "B",as.POSIXct("2002/04/11"),as.POSIXct("2012/04/12"),"5",
      "E",as.POSIXct("2000/02/10"),as.POSIXct("2005/02/15"),"6",
      "A",as.POSIXct("1985/02/10"),as.POSIXct("1987/06/10"),"7",
      "B",as.POSIXct("1989/02/11"),as.POSIXct("1990/02/12"),"8",
      "A",as.POSIXct("1997/05/15"),as.POSIXct("1999/06/15"),"9",
      "C",as.POSIXct("2010/08/29"),as.POSIXct("2015/08/29"),"10",
      "B",as.POSIXct("2010/04/11"),as.POSIXct("2012/04/12"),"11",
      "E",as.POSIXct("2004/02/10"),as.POSIXct("2005/02/15"),"12")
max_date = max(df$startdate,df$enddate)
```

Using the following code snippet:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(aes(y=loc, yend = loc, x = startdate, xend = enddate, colour=event),size = 5,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_label(aes(label=event, y = loc, x=max_date), size=2) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("LoC") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(event), scales = "free")
```

It generates the following plot:
[image]

I would like to order the LoC axis i.e primary Y-axis within the label i.e. event (secondary Y-axis). Within each label, it should print a point on the primary Y-axis in ascending order (For event C (4 -> 10) and E(6 -> 10) are already in ascending order). How can I order the other points in ascending order within each label i.e. event (I tried to sort data using `order` and `fct_inorder` from `forcats` library but couldn't able to achieve the desired result as shown below)? How can I print a single label within each group?
[image]

Please feel free to correct me!

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: It's already included in the 1st code snippet (last line): `max_date = max(df$startdate,df$enddate)`

Comment: Which label do you want? Just 1 at the top? on the row of the first/smallest loc?

Comment: I need only one label within each label group. It would be nice if we have a label on the first/smallest loc row (just above this row as highlighted in the 2nd image).

Comment: OK, I added the labels by using a new data frame to set the location and text of the labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with the package `forcats`.
`fct_inseq` for numeric order, and `fct_rev` to flip it depending if you want small->large or opposite.
I also added a `fct_reorder2` for your events (ordered by loc and enddate) but you might want to keep it in alphabetical order.

About your labels, it's probably best to create a new data frame to set where the labels are. I've done this below with group_by and summarize, and with other options in the comments below.

```r
library(tidyverse, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3
df <- tribble(~event, ~startdate,~enddate,~loc,
          "A",as.POSIXct("1984/02/10"),as.POSIXct("1987/06/10"),"1",
          "B",as.POSIXct("1984/02/11"),as.POSIXct("1990/02/12"),"2",
          "A",as.POSIXct("1992/05/15"),as.POSIXct("1999/06/15"),"3",
          "C",as.POSIXct("2003/08/29"),as.POSIXct("2015/08/29"),"4",
          "B",as.POSIXct("2002/04/11"),as.POSIXct("2012/04/12"),"5",
          "E",as.POSIXct("2000/02/10"),as.POSIXct("2005/02/15"),"6",
          "A",as.POSIXct("1985/02/10"),as.POSIXct("1987/06/10"),"7",
          "B",as.POSIXct("1989/02/11"),as.POSIXct("1990/02/12"),"8",
          "A",as.POSIXct("1997/05/15"),as.POSIXct("1999/06/15"),"9",
          "C",as.POSIXct("2010/08/29"),as.POSIXct("2015/08/29"),"10",
          "B",as.POSIXct("2010/04/11"),as.POSIXct("2012/04/12"),"11",
          "E",as.POSIXct("2004/02/10"),as.POSIXct("2005/02/15"),"12") %>%
  mutate(event = event %>% fct_reorder2(enddate, loc),
         loc = loc %>% fct_inseq() %>% fct_rev())
max_date = max(df$startdate,df$enddate)

df_for_labels <- df %>% group_by(event) %>% 
  summarize(date = max_date, # max(enddate) would give you the label at each event's max(enddate)
            loc = n()) # 1 for bottom-right. n() for top-right (counts number of rows in each event)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot(df)+
  geom_segment(aes(y=loc, yend = loc, x = startdate, xend = enddate, colour=event),size = 5,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_label(data = df_for_labels, aes(label=event, y = loc, x=date), size=2) +
  xlab("Year") + ylab("LoC") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(event), scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great! Could you please guide me how can I add only single label within a group?

Answer (score 1):

As `df$loc` is a character, when ggplot transforms it to factor to use it as a `color` argument, it selects it's levels by alphabetical order:

```
df$loc = as.factor(df$loc)
```

Which puts `"10"` in front of `"2"`. But you want it in numeric order, so you need to transform it to numeric by doing:

```
df$loc = factor(as.numeric(df$loc), levels=12:1)
```

The `levels=12:1` is to rearrange the order of your levels, and make the lower values appear before the big ones.

This solves the order. The labels i don't know how to solve.

Comment: With `df$loc = as.factor(as.numeric(df$loc))` it doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't help. I have already tried it.

Comment: I didn't test it before commenting, so sorry. Using `df$loc = factor(as.numeric(df$loc), levels=12:1)` worked for me, i have corrected it now.